# How do I pause a HashTag Feed in TweetDeck?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I'm using TweetDeck in both Google Chrome and with Adobe AIR.

When a really hot HashTag Feed comes along, it looks like a high-speed train going by and I can't read anything.

Is there anyway to pause the feed so that you can actually read the tweets? 
(Ya know aside from using twitter.com)

Comment: So there's no way to do this?  Unbelievable.

Comment: This really doesn't seem like the place for my question, since TweetDeck is a web-app (okay and a desktop app) but my question was referring to the web-app in Chrome.

Comment: I guess this doesn't work.  P.S. there's a desktop app for TweetDeck and a web app too.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in the Google Chrome App is to scroll the "feed bar" a little down, that way it will still update your feed BUT stop it from moving your scroll bar to the last message.

Comment: But when I let go, it will just start flying again, unless I have a second mouse cursor I can't click on a link that way...

Comment: thats weird, when I let go it stays there.